# How to manually map a List of object to a list of DTO?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have these:

```cs
public class FamilyHead
{
    public Guid HeadId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Citizen
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public short Age { get; set; }
    // more properties
    [ForeignKey("FamilyHead")]
    public Guid HeadId { get; set; }

    public virtual FamilyHead FamilyHead { get; set; }
}

public class CitizenDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public short Age { get; set; }
    public Guid HeadId
    public string HeadName { get; set; }
}
```

I can manually map it via extension method if it is a single instance:

```cs
public static CitizenDTO ToDTO(this Citizen citizen)
{
    if (citizen == null) return null;

    return new CitizenDTO {
        Id = citizen.Id,
        Name = citizen.Name,
        HeadId = citizen.HeadId,
        HeadName = citizen.FamilyHead.Name
    }   
}

var dto = aCitizen.ToDTO();
```

But how to map a list of citizens? I think `Select()` might do the work but I only know how to do it if the model and the dto have a same structure. Like this example:

```cs
IEnumerable<int> integers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
IEnumerable<string> strings = integers.Select(i => i.ToString());
```

So how to map a list of it?

Comment: Kindly update your question with `ToDTO` property in your `Citizen` class.. If you closely look into your question you missed it. If there is no property for `ToDTO` in `Citizen` class, then both answers will give you `Compile time error`

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar It is intended as an extension method `ToDTO()`. So I don't have to add a new property for it. Maybe your answer should call the method instead?

Comment: Your extension method is doing same as `Select` statement, which I wrote in my anawer. i.e. `dto.Add(citizen.ToDTO);` in foreach loop

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Oh snap, I made a typo then. It should call a method. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: ;) thanks for your update, I updated my answer too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Linq `Select()` as you used for `string` in your question, no need to write long extension method

```
IEnumerable<CitizenDTO> dto = citizens.Select(x => x.ToDTO());
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer before finishing my question. Just iterate through the list and add mapped DTO to it. Silly me

```cs
// Extension method
public static IEnumerable<CitizenDTO> ToDTO(this IEnumerable<Citizen> citizens)
{
    if (citizen == null) return null;

    var dto = new List<CitizenDTO>();

    foreach(var citizen in citizens) {
        dto.Add(citizen.ToDTO());   
    }

    return dto;
}

// How to use
IEnumerable<CitizenDTO> result = listOfCitizens.ToDTO();
```